# Delete all contents except for first row for specific sheets in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Please assist. I have this code here and it works for first sheet however, does not execute in the 2nd sheet. I think i'm missing a sheet syntax. thanks.

```
Dim arrSheets As Variant, sht As Variant

arrSheets = Array("tl_1", "tl_2")
For Each sht In arrSheets
  Sheets(sht).UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
Next sht
```

Comment: sht is a Variant, it is not an array of worksheets.  There is another way to step through the worksheets with out the array. See below.

Comment: What is `tl_1`? These are not declared or not shown here

Comment: Those are sheet names is what he is going for, wrap the code below in an IF, looking at your worksheets(N).Name or worksheets(N).CodeName if you only want to act upon a few sheets out of many.  I don't use arrays to iterate through the worksheets typically, or arrays of worksheet names, although I guess you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
'This will do something to your target sheets, 
'just make sure your "something" is what you want

Dim N As Long
Dim wsName As String

'Optional if included
For N = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    wsName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Name
    If wsName = "tl_1" or wsName = "tl_2" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(N).UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If
Next N
```

Note: This is very worksheet name dependent and users can change those if you are not the only user.  You may want to CodeName your sheets (properties Explorer and change the Name) then pull the CodeName.

You can use an array to hold the sheets names but it seems like more trouble than its worth unless you are going to load the names into the array.

-WWC

Comment: You commented this, but just wanted to doubly point out that this will execute on all Worksheets in the Workbook. From the OP's post, it looks like they only want to do this for the sheets called "tl_1" and "tl_2"

Comment: Thank you @ArcherBird, better to save him from deleting important data, added an if to only act on those two sheets . . .

Comment: Wrote my answer as you posted yours, sorry. Well, even CodeNames can change, hence my approach; the code wouldn't compile anymore should a CodeName change, giving the dev a heads up.

Comment: @Excelosaurus code name can only be changed through the *properties* toolwindow in the VBE. If a user changes that, and it breaks,....they asked for it.

Comment: @Mathier Guindon Sure. I was referring to devs who, in a refactoring frenzy, might change CodeNames. The code most probably won't compile anymore, letting them know they must refactor the code as well. My users can't get to the properties toolwindow ;-)

Comment: Glad it helped and it is easy to modify if you want to add more sheet names or perform a different action on the sheets (like a Case statement).  @Mathieu Guindon the one catch on Codenames is if the sheet is copied it enumerates it: example wsMySheet as a copy is wsMySheet1, and so on, but unless you want to run this code on copies as well the OP would be fine, we could make an Instr > 0 in the If and check for the original CodeName is contained and then it would run on the user Worksheet copies

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code that's kind of by design... code name uniquely identifies a worksheet that exists at compile-time. If you copied it, then the copy was created at run-time and therefore you should explicitly name it, ...and capture its reference in an object variable.

Comment: @AI5145 The best way to thank us is to mark the post as being the answer, which will grant points to the poster :-)

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents: do not rely on worksheet names. Instead, work with their (Name) property as seen from the Visual Basic Editor. Note that you can give significant names yourself instead of the default Sheet1..N ones. This way, your code will survive modifications to the names as seen from Excel, in the tabs at the bottom.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoTheClearThing()
    Dim loopVariant As Variant
    Dim loopWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim worksheetsToConsider As Variant

    'Use the (Name) property, as seen from the Visual Basic Editor, of the worksheets you're interested in.
    'The array below is not a string array; it is an array of worksheet objects.
    worksheetsToConsider = Array(TL_1, TL_2)

    'The For's variable must be a Variant; you can then Set it to a variable of the Worksheet type and enjoy Intellisense.
    For Each loopVariant In worksheetsToConsider
        Set loopWorksheet = loopVariant
        loopWorksheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's what the worksheets' (Name) properties look like in my test Excel workbook:
[image]

From within your workbook's code, you can directly interact with worksheet objects using their (Name) property. Avoid `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tl_1").SomeMethod` and directly go with `TL_1.SomeMethod`. By the way, a worksheet's (Name) property can be read by code using its `CodeName` property.

Comment: What @Excelosaurus said: Use worksheets.CodeName whenever possible over worksheets.Name, you don't want users changing your worksheets names and junking up your code.

Comment: To clarify: "whenever possible" is "whenever the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile time"

Comment: Good point @Mathieu Guindon, it does need to be a pre-existing sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet.UsedRange` does not always return the correct address.  Consider the results of the test below:

[image: UsedRange Test]

### Test Used Range

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range, target As Range

    Debug.Print "Data Range", "|"; "UsedRange"
    Debug.Print String(24, "_")

    With Worksheets.Add
        Set target = .Range("B2:D2")
        target.Value = 1
        Debug.Print target.Address, "|"; .UsedRange.Address
    End With

    With Worksheets.Add

        .Range("A1:G10").Interior.Color = 65535
        Set target = .Range("B2:D2")
        target.Value = 1

        Debug.Print target.Address, "|"; .UsedRange.Address
    End With

End Sub
```

### Clear Non-Headers

```
Sub ClearNonHeaderRows()
    Dim arrSheets As Variant, sht As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    arrSheets = Array("tl_1", "tl_2")
    For Each sht In arrSheets
        With Worksheets(sht).UsedRange
            Set cell = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1))
            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                cell.Offset(1).Resize(.Cells.Rows.Count - cell.row + .Cells(1, 1).row).EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next sht

End Sub
```